# Using Rxjs's `takeUntil` to auto unsubscribe - without waiting for emission?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I've already  read Ben's [*article*](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87) regarding unsubscribing via , `takeUntil` , `takeWhile`(*the predicate version*)

[*I've used it like this example in my Angular app*](https://alligator.io/angular/takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe/#unsubscribing-declaratively-with-takeuntil)

But  there is something which I don't understand.

Say I have an Observable which emit values after a long time :

```
const source = Rx.Observable.interval(10000);

var isContinue=true;

const example = source.takeWhile(val => isContinue)
                      .subscribe(val => {},()=>{},()=>console.log('complete'));

setTimeout(function (){isContinue=false},3000) //somewhere in destructor
```

Well , this will show "complete" only after 10 seconds and not after 3.

So basically if I have a component which subscribes to an Observable and that observable doesn't emit values for a long time , it will still have a reference to my object , causing slow memory leaks.

**Question:**

How can I use the takeWhile operator to unsubscribe as soon as I set the 
 `isContinue` value.

I don't want to trust a service which may not emit values and to keep a reference to my component.

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/xuvawefehe/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: You can call `unsubscribe` yourself on the `example` subscription. If you want to be sure some action happens when you either complete or unsubscribe you can use the `finally()` operator or manually add a dispose handler with `example.add(() => { console.log('complete') })`

Comment: @martin Thanks. so basically these operators can't be rely on. It will have to  emit at least one value *after takeWhile*  value was changed....in order to notice the change

Comment: Yes that's what `takeWhile` is for. But to be honest I don't understand what's the problem with `takeUntil`. I think it's the easiest way to go.

Comment: takeWhile should take your boolean, try this: `source.takeWhile(this.isContinue)`

Comment: @martin Will `takeUntil` solve the issue of "waiting forever" ? ( and to answer your question , I just dont think that a subject should be created only to notify someone about a flag changed)

Comment: @e.m.b _this.predicate is not a function_

Comment: @martin [I didn't know that takeUntil behaves differently](http://jsbin.com/sigihifote/1/edit?js,console). it actually aware when the value is changing and stops at the **moment** of `next` . Can you please explain why does takeUntil is aware and takeWhile is NOT aware ? Thank you

Comment: As for me it works as intended. http://take.ms/Pe98X

Comment: @yurzui Hi. Yes this is expected becuase the interval yielding data. But if you subscribe to a service which doesn't yet yield data ( look at my example , it's 10 seconds , while i want to quit at 3) , then a reference will keep remaining. So what about a service which doesn't emitting values for a LONG time ? all components will be kept in memory without unsubscribe. It seems that takewhile is not `aware-now-to-changes` while takeUntil **IS** `aware-now-to-changes` - http://jsbin.com/vojaposago/1/edit

Comment: Just write some code in `ngOnDestroy` like `this.isContinue = false` and `clearTimeout`

Comment: @yurzui But I did here ^ `setTimeout(function (){this.isContinue=false},3000) // simulate to code running in ngOnDestroy` , and still it didnt quit at 3 seconds. ( unless I don't follow you)

Comment: Do you use function expression or arrow function `setTimeout(() => {this.isContinue`? Prefer arrow function to keep `this` referring to the component instance

Comment: Your isContinue variable should be an angular component attribute, so that you can change it in different places, and in your takeWhile function use `this.isContinue`

Comment: @yurzui it's jsbin called at window , so no `this` , but even with `()=>` , it is not aware of breaking after 3 seconds. https://i.imgur.com/3CMTxsI.jpg

Comment: @yurzui mmm , same , it's is a property of `window`. and to clarify it , I've wrote it explicitly , still it breaks after 10 seconds and not 3.... https://i.imgur.com/Vw1AxQi.jpg ( just a reminder , with takeUntil with subject , it does works as expected)

Comment: I see. takeWhile will try to emit value after 10 sec. It doesn't subscribe on isContinue changes

Comment: @yurzui Yes. Exactly. and this can cause memory leaks if the obs$ is not emitting. However , from my testing , takeUntil (which takes a subject) does noticed immedialty to unsubscribe.

Comment: Then try `example.complete();` http://jsbin.com/kusezodaqe/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @yurzui How come `example` has a `complete` function ? From what I see it should be of type `ISubscription` where it only has  `  unsubscribe(): void;` method .... ?

Comment: I hacked it) Actually it returns `Subscriber` by it's typed as `Subscription`.

Comment: @yurzui Sorry i still dont understand where that complete function comes from. Can you please refernce a link ?

Comment: @martin  Why does the takeWhile is not aware of the variable , while takeUntil is aware of the subject being changed ?

Comment: `Why does the takeWhile is not aware of the variable?` Javascript can't do any magic if we don't tell how to do it. Changing variable has no effect for observable until it is checked whilst Subject notifies observable as soon as it emits new value.

Comment: `Observable.subscribe` returns `Subscription` https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/3ed75d5e40131cb5d9bbf146d543b2bbdbe067ba/src/internal/Observable.ts#L185-L198 But actually it returns Subscriber  https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/toSubscriber.ts#L6-L25 that extends `Subscription` and has `complete` method https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code produces the correct emissions - but your concern is the timeliness of the completion (it should complete after 3 seconds, not 10 seconds).

It takes 10 seconds as `takeWhile` only tests its predicate when the source observable emits.

`takeUntil` will fix this, but it needs an observable to wait on:

```
const source = Rx.Observable.interval(10000);

const abort = new Subject();

const example = source.takeUntil(abort)
                      .subscribe(val=>{}, ()=>{}, ()=>console.log('complete'));

setTimeout(function () {abort.next()}, 3000) //somewhere in destructor
```

Comment: I see. this difference should've been mentioned in the docs. Because ( like myself) , setting a  `Subject` only to emit a single value ever - seems weird. That's why I thought that listening to a `boolean` ( `takeWhile`) is a better option , but as you say , they behave differently. `takeUntil` is always watching the `subject` , regardless of emission , while `takeWhile` will consider the boolean value only at next(!) emission ( which may never come). 
Am I right  about the diagnostics ?

Comment: The main advantage of takeUntil is that under the hood it is itself subscribing.  In that sense it is not always watching - it is notified, so it acts immediately without expending any effort monitoring. I recommend it this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `isContinue` variable to `Observable` and subscribe to both of your observables: `source` and `isContinue`.

Comment: `takeWhile` can also return a boolean. so why it doesn't notice the changes in boolean  , but only after emission ? while takeUntil  ,does see the changes as they occur ?

Comment: It can return a boolean but it always should be applied on an `Observable`.

Comment: Can you please post an example ?